# Swift 5 SQLite Issue - "Unable to open database" suddenly

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I am developing an iOS app by using Xcode and SQLite is used for storing data.

There is an issue related the SQLite which is the exception "Unable to open database"/"cannot open file" when the app inserted a few thousands records into database.

One of the feature of my app is to download a JSON which contains about 1440 records (A record is a number with timestamp, such as {timestamp: '00:12', value: '29'} and insert those records into SQLite. I notice if I tried to download about 3~4 JSON, that exception will be appeared and the app will crash...

Is there any limitation on SQLite?

There is the code of inserting data:

```
//INSERT Statement
func insert(_ tableName :String, rowInfo :[String:String]) -> Bool {
    var statement :OpaquePointer? = nil
    let sql = "insert into \(tableName) " + "(\(rowInfo.keys.joined(separator: ","))) " + "values (\(rowInfo.values.joined(separator: ",")))"
    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(self.db, sql.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8), -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
        if sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE {
            return true
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement)
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: If you’re unable to open the database, you should share your open routine (including information about how you’re building the path to the database, etc.). We don’t need to see the `INSERT` code until we figure out why the opening of the database is failing. I wonder if you’ve got some hard-coded path outside of the app sandbox.

Comment: Unrelated (and don’t worry about this until you solve your database opening problem), you should be wary about building SQL statements with values in them. usually we use `?` placeholders in our SQL statement, and then use the [`sqlite3_bind_xxx`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) methods to bind values to these placeholders. Now, I’m guessing that you’re just inserting numeric values into your SQL statement, in which case you can get away with the above code, but in general, this would be considered an anti-pattern to be avoided.

Answer (score -1):

You must open database when perofrming action and When you’re done with a database connection, you’re responsible for closing it.

Try adding

```
sqlite3_open(db)
```

call at the function start.

And close database once operation is performed (here before return function) with:

```
sqlite3_close(db)
```